# Getting index of a value inside a json file PYTHON

Tags: python, json, indexing

I have a sizable json file and i need to get the index of a certain value inside it. Here's what my json file looks like:

data.json

```
   [{...many more elements here...
   },
   {
    "name": "SQUARED SOS",
    "unified": "1F198",
    "non_qualified": null,
    "docomo": null,
    "au": "E4E8",
    "softbank": null,
    "google": "FEB4F",
    "image": "1f198.png",
    "sheet_x": 0,
    "sheet_y": 28,
    "short_name": "sos",
    "short_names": [
      "sos"
    ],
    "text": null,
    "texts": null,
    "category": "Symbols",
    "sort_order": 167,
    "added_in": "0.6",
    "has_img_apple": true,
    "has_img_google": true,
    "has_img_twitter": true,
    "has_img_facebook": true
  },
  {...many more elements here...
  }]
```

How can i get the index of the value "FEB4F" whose key is "google", for example?

My only idea was this but it doesn't work:
print(data.index('FEB4F'))

Comment: What do you mean by "index?"  Do you want the position inside the _actual_, full JSON text?  Or are you looking for the _list_ index after parsing the JSON and looping over it?

Comment: Yes sorry i should mention it becomes a list when the file is imported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic data structure is a list, so there's no way to avoid looping over it.

Loop through all the items, keeping track of the current position.  If the current item has the desired key/value, print the current position.

```
position = 0
for item in data:
    if item.get('google') == 'FEB4F':
        print('position is:', position)
        break
    position += 1
```

Comment: You could also use `enumerate()` here instead of a `position` variable.  Like: `for position, item in enumerate(data):`

Comment: What if i dont' know that the key is google, how can i test just for 'FEB4F' ?

Comment: @Uriel: Then you'd have to loop over _every_ key/value pair, and check the value.

Comment: @Uriel Do you need to get what the key is?  Or do you just want the position?  If you just want the position, then you can try `if 'FEB4F' in item.values():`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat how can i display the list where that value exists in that index?

Comment: For example it returns 101 as index of "google", i need it to display the list or dictionary object like this:
{
    "name": "SQUARED SOS",
    "unified": "1F198",
    "non_qualified": null,
    "docomo": null,
    "au": "E4E8",
    "softbank": null,
    "google": "FEB4F",
    "image": "1f198.png",
    "sheet_x": 0,
    "sheet_y": 28,
    "short_name": "sos",
}

Comment: @Uriel You mean the _dict_ at the _position_ you've found?  That would be `data[position]`.

Comment: Or just `item`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data can fit in an table, I recommend using pandas for that. Here is the summary:

- Read de data using [pandas.read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)
- Identify witch column to filter
- Filter using [pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

IE:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_json("path_to_json.json")
print(data)

#lets assume you want to filter using the 'unified' column
filtered = data.loc[data['unified'] == 'something']
print(filtered)
```

Of course the steps would be different depending on the JSON structure